# @keyframes change content of an element

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am trying to create a keyframe what changes the content of an div container after a view seconds, but it don't work.

Here is my code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes k_home_projectSlider {
    0% {content: ".";}
    100% {content: "..";}
}
#home_projectSlider {
    height: 25em;
    width: 25em;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10em;
    animation: k_home_projectSlider 5s;
    -webkit-animation: k_home_projectSlider 5s;
}
```

My goal is to change the image, at the moment i don't know how often but more then 1 time. The problem is with the fiddle example the image don't fit in the div container although the background-size is set to the div width/height. But if i apply the keyframes style directly to the div it works fine.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hxksc6pu/)

Comment: As far as I know, animating `content` is not possible. Also `content` only applies to `::before` & `::after` not regular elements.

Comment: @Natsu hmm, ok thanks. So there is no other way then javascript :/

Comment: you could however, change images (if you had 1 dot, then two, then three, etc) it could work...

Comment: @Natsu i've already tried to change the background image with keyframes but the problem is the image size. My pictures have 500px width and height, but my div is 25em width and height. I know that i can set the background size thought background-size but this just work with i set it directly to the div but not as keyframe. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hxksc6pu/)

Comment: @Nimmi: You may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24488501/dynamically-changing-content-of-a-span/24491122#24491122) answer that I posted earlier mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-image` can be made to fit the size of the container `div` by using the following CSS properties.

```
background-size: cover; /* instructs that the image should be expanded to cover the size of the container */
background-repeat: no-repeat; /* instructs that the image shouldn't be repeated if it doesn't take full size of container */
```

```css
#slide {
  height: 25em;
  width: 25em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10em;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: animation 2s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
  from {
    background-image: url(http://reebokcrossfitbarecove.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Neuro-Linguistic-Programming.jpg);
  }
  to {
    background-image: url(http://www.manifestabundancenow.com/files/shutterstock_86188195.jpg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slide"></div>
```